# How to write SQL SELECT statement to return values ColumnA where ColumnB values = x and y and z only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

hoping someone will be able to help with what I think is probably a fairly straightforward T-SQL statement.

Using the table, 'ProductCommissionRates', below I'm trying to write a sql statement that will return all 'ProdCode' rows from the table where the 'ProdCode' has a 'CommRate' = '20', '25' and '30'. So in the example below I would expect the rows for 'ProdCode' = 07053 only to be returned

```
ProdCode    CommRate    RateDesc
00130       10      Desc 17
00130       20      Desc 18
00130       25      Desc 19
00130       28      Desc 20
00130       30      Desc 21
00130       50      Desc 23
07053       20      Desc 11
07053       25      Desc 12
07053       30      Desc 13
07246       20      Desc 5
07246       25      Desc 6
07246       30      Desc 7
07246       50      Desc 8
07493       20      Desc 1
07493       25      Desc 2
07493       30      Desc 3
07493       50      Desc 4
```

Comment: *"Using the table, 'ProductCommissionRates', below"* We can't *use* that table; it's an image not text. If you're supply sample data it needs to be at least `text`, so we can copy it and consume it,.

Comment: 00130 also have commRate `20, 25, 30`, why would it be excluded?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Can a prodCode have twice the same CommRate?

Comment: What is the ouput you want? 
only a list of ProdCode or all the rows?

Comment: @AXMIM I don't want 00130 returned because it also has CommRate values of 28 and 10. Essentially I only want the rows returned for ProdCodes where all of the CommRate values for the ProdCode in the table equal those specified in the Select statement. Yes, a ProdCode can have the same CommRate 'n' times. Using SQL Server 2016 and SSMS 17.9

Comment: @Larnu not sure how to provide the sample table data in txt...?

Comment: @Forpas has already demonstrated this to you since, IrunAzu .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested only in `ProdCode` then use this:

```
select ProdCode
from ProductCommissionRates
group by ProdCode
having 
  count(distinct case when CommRate in (20, 25, 30) then CommRate end) = 3
  and
  count(distinct CommRate) = 3
```

If you want also full rows from the table then:

```
select * from ProductCommissionRates
where ProdCode in (
  select ProdCode
  from ProductCommissionRates
  group by ProdCode
  having 
    count(distinct case when CommRate in (20, 25, 30) then CommRate end) = 3
    and
    count(distinct CommRate) = 3
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5731c5597c6b14d6a82df0e8ef01e454).
Results:

```
> ProdCode | CommRate | RateDesc
> -------: | -------: | :-------
>     7053 |       20 | Desc 11 
>     7053 |       25 | Desc 12 
>     7053 |       30 | Desc 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following if you just want the list of ProdCodes. Note you didn't give us any data to easily use so I created the minimum to answer your question.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1(Prodcode varchar(10),CommRate int)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('00130', 10)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('00130', 25)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('00130', 28)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('00130', 30)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('00130', 50)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('07053', 20)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('07053', 25)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('07053', 30)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('07246', 20)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('07246', 25)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('07246', 30)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES('07246', 50)

SELECT Prodcode
FROM #t1
WHERE CommRate in (20,25,30)
GROUP BY Prodcode
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT ProdCode
FROM #t1
WHERE CommRate NOT IN (20,25,30)
```

If you need to get the descriptions for all of those rows you and put it in a CTE and join it back to the table like such:

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (

    SELECT Prodcode
    FROM #t1
    WHERE CommRate in (20,25,30)
    GROUP BY Prodcode
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DISTINCT ProdCode
    FROM #t1
    WHERE CommRate NOT IN (20,25,30)
    )
SELECT tmp.* 
FROM #t1 tmp
INNER JOIN CTE t2 on tmp.Prodcode = t2.Prodcode
```